# Can't get Revmob to work with Flash CC/CS5.5

Tags: android, flash, actionscript, ads, revmob

I am trying to add revmob to my android app that I made in Flash CC. I am following there step by step guide on how to add it.  http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/air.html

I have a separate actionscript file i use to call the ad. But I am having trouble getting my xml file right.  Everytime I try to add their activity. I either get invalid element or application descriptor cannot be found.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!-- 
    Usage:

    To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.
    <description>
    <text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text>
    </description>

    To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.
    <name>
    <text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text>
    </name>
-->
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/13.0">


  <id>KatanaRun</id>
  <versionNumber>1.7.2</versionNumber>
  <versionLabel>1.7</versionLabel>
  <filename>Katana Run</filename>
  <description/>
  <name>Katana Run</name>
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>KatanaRun3.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image36x36>KatanaRunImages/36x36IconBURNED.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>KatanaRunImages/48x48IconBURNED.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>KatanaRunImages/72x72IconBURNED.png</image72x72>
    <image96x96>KatanaRunImages/96x96IconBURNED.png</image96x96>
  </icon>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>





 <android>

    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>


  </android>

  <extensions>
    <extensionID>com.revmob.airextension</extensionID>
  </extensions>
</application>
```

This is my current code for my xml file.
I need help figuring out where to add these lines.
At lease I'm pretty sure that's what's not working if anyone could help me more tell me what im doing wrong that would be great.

```
<manifestAdditions>
    <![CDATA[
       <manifest android:installLocation='auto'>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
          <application android:enabled="true">
             <activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
                   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            </activity>
        </application>
      </manifest>
    ]]>
</manifestAdditions>






<application>
    <activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at their documentation website: http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/air.html ?

There, you can see their RevMobSampleApp-app.xml. The way they do it is:

```
<icon></icon>
<android>
  <manifestAdditions>
    <![CDATA[
      <manifest android:installLocation='auto'>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <application android:enabled="true">
          <activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
          </activity>
        </application>
      </manifest>
    ]]>
  </manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

and it works!